# Excel VBA Macro - Prompt for Column Description to Assert Range

Tags: vba, excel

I have searched long for an answer to this:

Using code below I would like to enter an empty row at the end of each set of unique values.  The kicker is, I'd like it to have a prompt that allows the user to key letters for the column range.  I've tried a number of them out, cannot replace "B" with a query answer.

```
Dim lRow As Long
For lRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
If Cells(lRow, "B") <> Cells(lRow - 1, "B") Then Rows(lRow).EntireRow.Insert
Next lRow
End Sub
```

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim sCol As String
    sCol = InputBox("Enter Column", sCol)
    For lRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, sCol).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
        If Cells(lRow, sCol) <> Cells(lRow - 1, sCol) Then
            Rows(lRow).Insert
        End If
    Next lRow
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess your question is, you want user to be able to input "B", "AA", "C" as the column?

partial copying @Chris's code

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim sCol As String
    Dim colNum as string
    sCol = InputBox("Enter Column", sCol)
    colNum  = columns(sCol).column
    For lRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, colNum  ).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
        If Cells(lRow, colNum  ) <> Cells(lRow - 1, colNum  ) Then
            Rows(lRow).Insert
        End If
    Next lRow
End Sub
```

Comment: What your point Lary?  Using my code the user _does_ enter `B`, `AA`, `C` etc

Comment: @chrisneilsen I tested your code just now, and I **just** learn the new syntax `cells(rowNumber, columnSymbol)`. Thanks! But I still prefer number more, so it can be easily offset, iterate..

Answer (score 0):

Try `Range("B" & Cells.Rows.Count)` instead of `Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "B")` and similarly for the rest.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I gave that a try, but no such luck.  Allow me to clarify: I'd like to use an Inputbox to 'ask' for "B".  That way, it will act on any column the user inputs.  Is there a generic command that I could use in place of B, or would I need to set that?

Comment: @user2043959 oh I see buddy, sorry. My VBA experience is yet far from user-input forms. Hope someone else will help.

Comment: Thanks anyway.  

I just started with it, myself.  Does *most* of the things that I want it to...

Comment: @user2043959 so Good luck with your learning. Got my +1 for the question since I'm interested in the solution as well.

Comment: Hey thanks.  I'll post a solution if I find an appropriate answer before anyone here.

Answer (score 0):

Including open prompt, this is what I ended up using.
connected the open prompt to a button to make it easier for non-techies to use:

```
Sub InsertRowAtChangeInValue()

    Dim customerBook As Workbook
    Dim filter As String
    Dim caption As String
    Dim customerFilename As String
    Dim customerWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook

    Set targetWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook

    filter = "Excel 2007 files (*.xlsx),*.xlsx, Excel 97-03 files (*.xls),*xls, All files (*.*),*.*"
    caption = "Please select an input file."
    customerFilename = Application.GetOpenFilename(filter, , caption)

    Set customerWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(customerFilename)

    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Set targetSheet = targetWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Set sourceSheet = customerWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

    targetSheet.Range("A1", "AR5000").Value = sourceSheet.Range("A1", "AR5000").Value

    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim sCol As String
    Dim colNum As String
    sCol = InputBox("Enter Column", sCol)
    colNum = Columns(sCol).Column
    For lRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, sCol).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
        If Cells(lRow, sCol) <> Cells(lRow - 1, sCol) Then
            Rows(lRow).Insert
        End If
    Next lRow
End Sub
```

Thanks again for the help!